# Create reusable factory for code generation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I have 130 lines of code with similar Ruby code:

```
@acquirer = create(:acquirer,
                   name: 'OmniPay Datawire acquirer',
                   country_code: 372,
                   timezone: 'Europe/Dublin'
                  )

@reseller = create(:reseller,
                   name: 'OmniPay Datawire reseller',
                   domain: 'op-res-domain')
@merchant = create(:merchant,
                   name: 'OmniPay Datawire Merchant',
                   state_raw: 2,
                   supported_features: 15,
                   merchant_owner: @reseller,
                   login: 'test',
                   pwd: 'test',
                   notification_url: 'http://127.0.0.1/notification_url')

@contract = create(:contract_supports_all,
                   name: 'Omnipay Datawire Contract',
                   gateway: 'test',
                   mpi: 'test',
                   acquirer: @acquirer,
                   contract_owner: @reseller,
                   merchant: @merchant,
                   descriptor: 'Descriptor',
                   activated: '1',                       
                  )
```

How I can create factory method for reusing this code?

I would like to save as much as possible space. Can you show me some very useful example which I can use as solution?

Comment: Ever thought of using https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

or https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication

Comment: @NickM i think that  author use FactoryGril.

Answer (score 0):

You can create module with method which will populate data:

```
# spec/support/sample

module Sample
  def populate_data
    @acquirer = create(:acquirer,
               name: 'OmniPay Datawire acquirer',
               country_code: 372,
               timezone: 'Europe/Dublin'
              )

    @reseller = create(:reseller,
               name: 'OmniPay Datawire reseller',
               domain: 'op-res-domain')
    @merchant = create(:merchant,
               name: 'OmniPay Datawire Merchant',
               state_raw: 2,
               supported_features: 15,
               merchant_owner: @reseller,
               login: 'test',
               pwd: 'test',
               notification_url: 'http://127.0.0.1/notification_url')

    @contract = create(:contract_supports_all,
               name: 'Omnipay Datawire Contract',
               gateway: 'test',
               mpi: 'test',
               acquirer: @acquirer,
               contract_owner: @reseller,
               merchant: @merchant,
               descriptor: 'Descriptor',
               activated: '1',                       
              )
  end
end
```

and include it in test:

```
require 'support/sample'

#spec/sample_test_spec

describe 'test something' do
 include Sample

 before do
   populate_data
 end

 it 'test something' do
   expect(@acquirer).to_not be nil
 end

end
```